# Message from Yup custom validator returns undefined for the names of path and reference

Tags: node.js, express, validation, yup

I am trying to write a custom test for the yup validation library for use in a node/express app that tests whether two fields are the same - use case e.g. testing whether password and confirm password fields match. The logic is working, however the message provided from the method is not.

Custom validator code modified from: https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/97#issuecomment-306547261

**Custom validator**

```js
yup.addMethod(yup.string, 'isMatch', function (ref, msg) {
  return this.test({
    name: 'isMatch',
    message: msg || `${this.path} must be equal to ${this.reference}`,
    params: {
      reference: ref.path
    },
    test: function (value) {
      return value === this.resolve(ref);
    }
  });
});
```

**Example use**

```js
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  password: yup.string().min(8),
  passwordConfirm: yup.string().isMatch(yup.ref('password'))
})

const payload = {
  password: 'correctPassword',
  passwordConfirm: 'incorrectPassword'
}

schema.validate(payload)
```

The above method works as expected from a logic perspective. However, in the error message returned, the value of `this.path` and `this.reference` are both `undefined` (i.e. `undefined must be equal to undefined`). It should read `passwordConfirm must be equal to password`.

I had to add `this.` in front of `path` and `reference`, otherwise node crashes with a ReferenceError that `path/reference is not defined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to write a custom validation function to check if two fields match, you can use the built in validator`.oneOf`

> Whitelist a set of values. Values added are automatically removed
>   from any blacklist if they are in it. The ${values} interpolation can
>   be used in the message argument.
>
> Note that undefined does not fail this validator, even when undefined
>   is not included in arrayOfValues. If you don't want undefined to be a
>   valid value, you can use mixed.required.

See here [ref: oneOf(arrayOfValues: Array, message?: string | function): Schema Alias: equals](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedoneofarrayofvalues-arrayany-message-string--function-schema-alias-equals)

So you could re-write your schema as follows (I've added required also to the password fields):

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  password: yup.string().min(8).required('Required!'),
  passwordConfirm: yup.string().oneOf([Yup.ref('password')], 'Password must be the same!').required('Required!')
})
```